# How do I change the player model to a BlockBench made model in minecraft forge 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have created a custom model in BlockBench and I am trying to override the rendering of the players model.

The code in the class for the model I created is

```java
package com.example.examplemod;// Made with Blockbench 4.4.3
// Exported for Minecraft version 1.7 - 1.12
// Paste this class into your mod and generate all required imports

import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBase;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBox;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelRenderer;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;

public class custom_model extends ModelBase {
    private final ModelRenderer bb_main;

    public custom_model() {
        textureWidth = 16;
        textureHeight = 16;

        bb_main = new ModelRenderer(this);
        bb_main.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        bb_main.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bb_main, 0, 0, -1.0F, -2.0F, -1.0F, 2, 2, 2, 0.0F, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Entity entity, float f, float f1, float f2, float f3, float f4, float f5) {
        bb_main.render(f5);
    }

    public void setRotationAngle(ModelRenderer modelRenderer, float x, float y, float z) {
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleX = x;
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleY = y;
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleZ = z;
    }
}
```

This is how I called my class when the PlayerRenderEvent.Pre is called

```java
@EventHandler
public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(PlayerRenderEventClass.class);
}
```

This is where the code to cancel the render of the default skin is,  and I am trying to render my new model but it Gives a null pointer exception at the line where player is a parameter of the PlayerModel.render() method.  I have also tried to use event.getPlayer and event.getLivingEntity both gave NPE

```java
package com.example.examplemod;


import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.RenderPlayerEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.obj.OBJLoader;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

import java.lang.ref.Reference;

public class PlayerRenderEventClass {
    public static custom_model PlayerModel;

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void PlayerRenderEvent(RenderPlayerEvent.Pre event) {
        event.setCanceled(true);
        Entity player = event.getEntity();
        if (player != null) {
            PlayerModel.render(
                    player,
                    0.0F,
                    0.0F,
                    0.0F,
                    0.0F,
                    0.0F,
                    0.65F);
        }
    }

}
```

I havent programmed Minecraft mods in a while and have very little clue whats going on,   any help would be appreciated, lmk if you need any other information.  The program only crashes when you go into 3rd person which is when I assume the RenderPlayerEvent is called,  Basically the screen void blue,  I think nothing is getting rendered and its just the skybox,  and then it crashes

I have tried changing the `event.getEntity()` to `event.getLivingEntity()`, and `event.getPlayer()`,  neither of which worked.

I am expecting my player model to be replaced with the one I created in BlockBench.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [GeckoLib](https://geckolib.com/)? I've been using it and I think it's your answer. Unfortunately while trying to answer your question with an example I can across a difficult error. I hope this helps! Will let you know as soon as I have a full solution!

Installation: [Forge](https://github.com/bernie-g/geckolib/wiki/Installation#for-forge-use)/[Fabric](https://github.com/bernie-g/geckolib/wiki/Installation#for-fabric-use)
Documentation: [GitHub](https://github.com/bernie-g/geckolib)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).